# How did the prefix 'be-' function in 'behind'?

Tags: etymology, affixes

> [behind (adv.)](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=behind&allowed_in_frame=0)
>       Old English *behindan* "behind, after,"
>   from ***bi* "by"** + *hindan* "`from behind`" (see [hind (adj.)](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=hind&allowed_in_frame=0)).

*hindan* already meant "from behind", and It doesn't make sense to  say: **by** `from behind`.
 So why was ***bi* "by"** added as a prefix? 
How did ***bi* "by"** contribute to 'behind'?

Unlike Etymonline above, [OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/17226?redirectedFrom=behind#eid) doesn't pinpoint the matching definition of the prefix *be-*.

Comment: The be (in before, below, beyond, behind) is the ancestor of "by" (in OE, it was often written bi- as well) just as in Present Day German "bei" and is originally a spatial reference to oneself (as in close by, nearby, stand by me etc).

Comment: It is [found in many Germanic languages](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix:Proto-Germanic/bi-).  Logically speaking, it is justified as a reference point. *hindan* only provides the direction ("backwards") and *be* provides the additional point of reference precision ("behind what?" => behind myself).

Comment: @AlainPannetier Thanks. I did your excellent answer at ELU: http://english.stackexchange.com/a/26019/50720

Answer (score 3):

This "be-" prefix (originally *bi-*) was originally used to create prepositions—compare *fore* against *before*, *hind* against *behind*, *twain* against *between*, *low* against *below*, and so on.

In essence, the prefix isn't adding any new semantic meaning: it's just changing the part of speech and attaching a reference point to the description. "Hind" is an adjective describing anything at the back (as in "hindmost"), but "behind" attaches that back-ness to a fixed reference point: you can be hindmost, but you can't be *hindmost the house; you can only be *behind* the house.

Comment: Does the prefix itself come from anything in particular? Like "by" (thinking of "because", which has "by cause" as its etymology, but these might be different)?

Comment: @LjL I believe it's cognate with "by", and also with Greek *epi* and Latin *ob* (each from a different PIE grade).

Comment: Please qualify the period for which this is true; The question is interesting because prefixes have a tendency to converge. *be-* is a frequent suffix in German, but mostly verbal. There's a curious notion that *bevor* is partly similar in German (e.g. verbal in *bevorstehen*), but *behind-* implies retardation, or a hindernis, thus *behindert*, "handicapped", *behindern*, "to hinder, block"; *''Passive'' zurück geblieben* is a common euphemism for arrested development, but *zurück bleiben* is also simply "to stay behind". *hinter mir* "beh. me", or *Hintern* "buttocks" do not need the suffix.

Comment: Ger. *Hinterbliebene* exclusively means "living relatives of a deceased person", analoguous to *Hinterlassenschaften* "remains, inheritance", though the latter is not as exclusive. Thus I suspect a connection to the topic of *orphanage* (viz. *behindert* and a suppression of *behind-* as preposition in German due to taboo. I hope this can inform En. *behind* though I do not quite see how, as the development may be separate, not tangential nor original. For now I'd suspect that *to hinder* tabooized *_-hinder* by parallel development, but I do not see how.

Comment: *be-* might trivially compare to *to be*, with equally loose semantics as *by-* (e.g. *bygone*, Ger. *begangen*; cp. *begehen*, "to cause"? "to commit, hold, go on"). Compare *who is behind this* to Ger. *wer steckt da-hinter* (cp. *Ver-steck* "hide-out", or maybe *to stalk*, *who's stalking out there?*). *hint-* straight from a PIE root \*Henteros without any influence of *under* or *anti* is difficult, if there is so much potential for confusion across isoglosses (what with "up, ob, ab, auf, of, off, aft* etc. Comparing *über* and *over*, En. *be-* may be one of the senses of Ger. *ver-* ...

Comment: ... and the similarity of *before, bevor* explained differently, e.g. induced by contact. That is, *in some limited sense, *ver-* better compares to \bher- "to bare, carry" or "to fare". There are so many roots \*Cer- "to carry", that telling them appart with just a couple of soundlaws for millenia of development without material evidence must be deemed insufficient. *etw. vertragen* "to move sth." (not 1. "to reconcile, contract") is a weak pointer in that direction, IMHO. Further cp. *preterite*, *carried out* and more.

Comment: Finally, I suppose *be-* might be the head, and *-hind* a suffix; cp. aforementioned *hide* and also *to hang*, Ger. pret. *hing-, hang-* (viz. e.g. *Anhang* "relatives, followers, support"), Ger. *hin* "to, there", *dahin* "away, off, broken", *da hin* "to there", *auf und ab, hin und her*, "up and down, back and forth" (with *her* often compared to *hier* "here"; and *hin* thus as the opposite).

Comment: That's more aptly *up and down, to and fro*. ... What about epenthesis from an aspirated [bʰ] to /bif/ in \*\*bvor that went to /f, v/ elsewhere? Alternatively cp. [ambi-, ambo](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ambo#Latin).